# failing to find mocked service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I am noticing that the error is occurring on the line: `{ provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService },`, not inside any tests. In fact, I can set breakpoints in chrome at the first line inside of each `beforEach` and `ìt` (at *TestBed..., fixture...,* and *expect...*), as well as entirely swap out my component for a dummy *AltTestComponent*, and it **still fails** with the same error before reaching a breakpoint. At that point, the only reference to AppConfigService at all is in the `{ provide ... }` statement.

### component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Inject } from '@angular/core';
import { AppConfigService } from '@our/common-components';

import { WINDOW_LOCATION_TOKEN } from '@src/utils/location';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-my-status',
  templateUrl: './my-status.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['../styles/index.scss', './my-status.component.scss']
})
export class MyStatusComponent implements OnInit {    
  constructor(private appConfigService: AppConfigService,  @Inject(WINDOW_LOCATION_TOKEN) private location: Location) { }

...
```

### spec

```
import { async, ComponentFixture, TestBed } from '@angular/core/testing';
import { ButtonModule, AppConfigService } from '@our/common-components';

import { WINDOW_LOCATION_TOKEN } from '@src/utils/location';
import { MyStatusComponent } from './my-status.component';

class MockAppConfigService {}

const dummyLocation = { href: '' };

describe('MyStatusComponent', () => {
  let component: MyStatusComponent;
  let fixture: ComponentFixture<MyStatusComponent>;

  beforeEach(async(() => {
    TestBed.configureTestingModule({
      imports: [
        ButtonModule
      ],
      declarations: [ MyStatusComponent ],
      providers: [
        { provide: AppConfigService, useClass: MockAppConfigService },
        { provide: WINDOW_LOCATION_TOKEN, useValue: dummyLocation }
      ],
    })
    .compileComponents();
  }));
...
```

result:

```
Error: StaticInjectorError(DynamicTestModule)[MyStatusComponent -> AppConfigService]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[MyStatusComponent -> AppConfigService]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for AppConfigService!
```

The module that loads the component doesn't directly provide **AppConfigService**. Instead, it imports a module from our common-components package, which provides it with a *forRoot* method. I am noticing that it does not *export* it (and cannot, ModuleWithProviders has no property for exports), is that the reason? Is there no workaround?

tried:

- Making the mock service `@Injectable`
- using an instance of the object with `useValue: new Mock...` instead of `useClass`
- both of those together

Comment: Are your common components installed as a dependency normally? Seen something similiar recently when usin `npm link`

Comment: you mean are they an npm package? yes, we build them as a separate npm

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to make MockAppConfigService @Injectable().